# Shell Script Error using Cygwin

Tags: shell, cygwin

I got this error:

```
./script_test.sh

./script_test.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''

'/script_test.sh: line 3: `for ((j=0; j<"$N"; j++)) ; do
```

!/bin/sh
This script will launch 10 simulations for each value of the PARAM1_LIST.
Simulations results will be stored in folders named "myTest-i-j", where i
is the effective value of the PARAM1_LIST for each simulation and j
is the 1 to 10 repetition for each i.

```
N=10
PARAM1_LIST=(1 2 5 10)
for (( j = 0 ; j < $N; j++ )); do
for i in ${PARAM1_LIST[@]}; do
java -jar N3Sim.jar myConfigFile.cfg myTest-${i}-${j} $i
done
done
```

Any Help Would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The code in the error and the code in your example don't line up, and there is nothing wrong with the code in your example. Make sure $N isn't in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` does not treat the DOS-standard `\r\n` as the end-of-line marker, so the `\r` is treated as a normal character, which fouls up its parsing. You need to change the line endings to be `\n` only.

Comment: And the way to do that is with `dos2unix`, which is part of the Cygwin base installation.

Comment: Thank you guys. Its working now. I just need to convert to unix format using dos2unix in cygwin.